# Cordova or Phonegap? Which one?

Tags: mobile, cordova

I'm a Web Designer and Web Developer, I want to switch to cross platform mobile framework, so I want use Cordova or Phonegap .

But my question is which one is better or overall what's the difference between these frameworks? `Phonegap` is an Adobe product and `Cordova` is an Apache product.

I do not know which one should I choose and learn?

Comment: If you want to use phonegap build service use phonegap, if not, use cordova. Phonegap is cordova + build on cloud service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap is powered by the code of Cordova. I encourage you to search on Google for a precise answer. Here are a couple links about that subject. http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/
http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-03-26/demystifying-apache-cordova-and-phonegap

To answer your question; they do the same thing but PhoneGap have more functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Recently phoneGap released an amazing dev tool : http://app.phonegap.com/

The PhoneGap Developer App
Develop locally then see the changes instantly on your mobile device.